# if (mask & VALUE) or if ((mask & VALUE) == VALUE)?

Tags: c++, bitmask

You're probably familiar with the `enum` bitmask scheme, like:

```
enum Flags {
    FLAG1 = 0x1,
    FLAG2 = 0x2,
    FLAG3 = 0x4,
    FLAG4 = 0x8,

    NO_FLAGS = 0,
    ALL_FLAGS = FLAG1 | FLAG2 | FLAG3 | FLAG4
};

f(FLAG2 | FLAG4);
```

I've seen a lot of code that then tests for a certain bit in the mask like

```
if ((mask & FLAG3) == FLAG3)
```

But isn't that equivalent to this?

```
if (mask & FLAG3)
```

Is there some reason to use the first version?  In my opinion, the second shorter version is more legible.

Maybe leftover habits from C programmers who think true values should be converted to `1`?  (Though even there, the longer version makes more sense in an assignment or `return` statement than in a conditional statement test.)

Comment: Now do it with mask & ALL_FLAGS.  No longer the same.

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `&`, so you need parentheses in your condition: `if ((mask & FLAG3) == FLAG3)`.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The construct `if ((mask & FLAG3) == FLAG3)` tests if **all** bits in FLAG3 are present in mask; `if (mask & FLAG3)` tests if **any** are present.

If you know FLAG3 has exactly 1 bit set, they are equivalent, but if you are potentially defining compound conditions, it can be clearer to get into the habit of explicitly testing for all bits, if that's what you mean.

Comment: It also behaves differently if `FLAG == 0` (which... can happen)

Answer (score 3):

When it is for a bitset, so you have to compare just a **single** bit, it is okay to have `if(mask & value)`.

But, suppose that you have an IP address stored on ant `int32` and you want to know whether it is `192.168.*`, then you will have to do:

```
if((ip & 0xFFFF0000) == 0xC0A80000) // assuming some endianness representation.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your condition will be true if the result is non-zero. In your example, the result of both operations would be equivalent, and the second option could even be slightly faster because some CPUs can test for zero easier than other arbitrary numbers, BUT:

Obviously, you can't do the second option if the value you're checking for consists of more than one bit. In that case, you have to use the first option. That obviously also applies if you're checking for several bits at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Even for the single-bit value where these statements are actually equivalent, I always favour the explicit comparison.

1. It makes the intent clearer. We really *are* interested in comparing flags. `(x & Flag) == Flag` is an established pattern and I can process and recognize it at the blink of an eye.
2. I usually prefer explicit over implicit conversions. I make an exception for fail states (e.g. I write `if (file)` instead of `if (file.good())`) but when working with numbers, 0 is not a “fail state”, it’s a number like any others. I don’t like treating it differently in a boolean context.

Comment: Your code in point (1) is incorrect. Because of operator precedence in C and C++, you need to add parentheses to get the intended effect. A common gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

`if` takes a boolean (`bool`). The former expression is directly of type `bool`, whereas the latter is a numeric value which will be implicitly converted to `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

The first construct, `if (mask & FLAG3)` means "if at least one common bit is in the flag and mask".  For example, `if (formats & supported_formats)` would be true if **any** bit were in common between formats and supported_formats.

The second construct, `if (mask & FLAG3) == FLAG3` means "if all set bits in FLAG3 are set in the mask".  For example,  `if (things_you_have & things_required) == things_required` would be true if **all** things_required were in things_you_have.

Here's a quick hit of some special cases:

- For `FLAG_WITH_EXACTLY_ONE_BIT_SET`, both cases work.
- For `OBSOLETE_FLAG_SET_TO_ZERO`, the first case always returns false.
- For `FLAG_WITH_MULTIPLE_BITS_REQUIRED`, or `FLAG_WHICH_IS_REALLY_TWO_FLAGS_COMBINED_WITH_AN_OR`, the first case returns true when it should not. The second case returns correctly.

If you have the case of a FLAG_WITH_EXACTLY_ONE_BIT_SET, you should code with the second construct to avoid strange problems when the flag value gets changed.  Be explicit unless your profiler tells you to squeeze out every operation.